# Helvetica font screw Google Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google

I have installed "Helvetica" in Ubuntu, but it have a bug with Google Chrome. Well, I removed it from `~/.fonts/` folder, but the problem persist.

The problem is that Chrome (and also any Electron app, like Wmail) render the Helvetica font without spaces and with blue circle around the number, as you can see in the previous screenshot.

Here are two screenshot of the problem

[image: helvetica problem]

And after I replaced the font with Arial, this was the result

[image]

There is any other font folder or any font cache that Ubuntu store for Google Chrome?

Comment: What bug? What problem? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Here is a screenshot. http://imgur.com/SZSSxom

Comment: Please add a _real_ screenshot. It's very difficult to recognize any problem with the provided one. And please be precise when you say "problem".

Comment: The problem is that Chrome (and also any Electron app, like Wmail) render the Helvetica font without spaces and with blue circle around the number, as you can see in the previous screenshot. I just upload two screenshots from Wmail, with and without the "Helvetica" font - http://imgur.com/a/4JhYt.

I already deleted any "Helvetica" font in ~/.fonts and /usr/share/fonts/ and used the fc-cache -rf, so I don't understand why this happen.

Comment: What's the link of the pages? btw, why do you think the font set there is helvetica? Which version of chrome do you use? Also can you go to the "Computed" tab of the "Element" category and see the name of the font?

Comment: And what is the output of `fc-match 'Helvetica'`? command

Comment: The output is that:
'n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"'

Comment: The screenshot were taken on the Wmail webapp, but the same happen in Google Chrome and even on Rambox (that use Electron also). 

My Google Chrome is the latest (58), and about Wmail and Rambox I'm not sure what version it is.

I'm sure that the problem is with Helvetica because I can Inspect the element and remove Helvetica and everything work just fine (as you can see on the screenshot before).

Comment: I found some answers around the web to use the Stylish extensions and use this code to remove Helvetica:

....font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }
....font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
.....font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'Helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }

But for Electron apps isn't enough, also, I don't want to install an extension just for that.

Comment: I just saw the same issue on two machines running Zesty, but only in Chromium (Firefox works fine). https://askubuntu.com/a/921610/25639 solved it for me, but maybe this should be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that you can edit the font used to match the "Helvetica"

In terminal, `fc-match "Helvetica"` shows that Helvetica wasn't set (or is set to a bad font).

Make a new file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/99-my-fix-missing-helvetica-spaces.conf` to set it to a working font:

`<fontconfig>
  <match>
    <test name="family"><string>Helvetica</string></test>
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">
      <string>Liberation Sans</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>`

(You could use e.g. `fc-match Arial` if you want to use the same one as the one matching Arial.)

Problem solved :)

Source: https://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-to-set-default-fonts-and-font-aliases-on-linux.html

Answer (score 2):

The font causing the problem is "Emoji One". I had the same problem and after removing the package fonts-emojione, the problem was gone.

Comment: This seems to be the actual bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-emojione/+bug/1671850

Answer (score 0):

Wide system fonts are locate at:

```
/usr/share/fonts/
```

and for each user as you know we have:

```
~/.fonts
```

Also after removing a font you should run:

```
fc-cache -rf
```

to regenerate fonts cache. Try removing Google Chrome caches too it might help you.

Comment: I tried that, no success. I delete every "Helvetica" font from my computer. 

http://imgur.com/SZSSxom